# Auto Updating Databinding

Tags: c#, data-binding, dataset

I have a collection of objects (List) that is bound to a datagridview.  How when I add or remove an object from the collection, can it refresh the datagridview without rebinding the control?

Comment: asp.net? winform or wpf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also found the way I was thinking of in another question ([This one to be specific](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630343/correct-way-to-have-a-datagridview-visually-reflect-changes-in-its-datasource))... guess I didn't search long enough.

> The correct way is for the data-source to implement IBindingList, return true for SupportsChangeNotification, and issue ListChanged events. However, AFAIK, a DataView does this...

by Marc Gravell

Answer (score 0):

- Call the EndCurrentEdit() method of the DataGridView's BindingContext.
- Refresh first the DataGridView and then the Parent (form or other container)