# Form2 changes does not reflect the changes in Form1

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a problem with datagridview.

Form 1 : populating data with datagridview ...(when i click on the datagrid view row the corresponding row values are transferred to another form)

Form 2 : i have text buttons with save button

when i click on the datagrid view row the values are transferred to another form this is working fine.....

in form 2 i have done some changes with that data but this changes does not reflect in the form 1 datagrid view ...

How can i solve this problem.....

Comment: Do you work with database? Where does the data come from, if not?

Comment: Anyway, this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/630343/correct-way-to-have-a-datagridview-visually-reflect-changes-in-its-datasource

Comment: i am working with databases...... the binding the datagrid view using binding source...

Comment: @shadow there is no another form mentioned in that post...

Comment: Other form is not relevant, it doesn't matter how the data is being changed or where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few options for you. Passing the Form1 instance to the Form2 and refresh the Form1 DataGridView dataSource from Form2 is one option.

For example. Form2 constructor can be like below

```
Form1 myForm1;

public Form2(Form1 form1)
{
    myForm1 = form1;
}

private void SaveButtonClicked()
{
    //Refresh the Form1.DataGridView DataSource.
}
```

**Method2**

You can call a method to refresh the Form1 DataGridView in Form1 by creating an event in Form2.

Answer (score 1):

To answer this question we have to know how you are passing the values of the selected GridRow to the controls of the other form.

if your grid is bound to a dataset/datatable for example, once you select a row in the UI and another form is shown with the fields of that DataGridRow being exploded into different controls, what objects do you pass to the other form?

I would for example pass the DataRow linked to the selected row in the grid, this way in the second form you still have a reference to the datarow and when somebody changes a value in the textbox ( for example ) you could manually update the datarow column's value with the new value entered by the user.

in this way if in the previous form you refresh the grid you will see the changes.

*Please note this can be done in many different ways and I would not probably use exactly this approach if I could write the whole logic from scratch, but you are telling too little so can't suggest anything more for now.*

Answer (score 0):

If you are showing Form2 using ShowDialog() method then this call will pause Form1 until Form2 is NOT closed.

This is the simplest approach. E.g.

```
Form1 {
    UpdateRowMethod() {
      DataRow Row = GetSelectedRow()
      Form2 frm;
      frm = new Form2(Row.Field1, Row.Field2, Row.Field3)
      if frm.ShowDialog() = OK {
         Row.Field1 = frm.Property1
         Row.Field2 = frm.Property2
         Row.Field3 = frm.Property3
         DataGridView1.InvalidateSelectedRow()
      }
   }
}
```

And as you can see Form2 is accepting the Field Values of Row as parameters of its constructor. And Form2 is returning back the updated data through its properties.

And If you are using Show() method then you need to implement events/delegates in order to notify Form1 that data has been changed.

Answer (score 0):

Create a BindingSource in Form1, use that to fill DataGridView in Form1. Pass the BindingSource to Form2, before invoking it. All your changes will get automatically wired in/out. You will not need to expose any property in Form2 other than the BindingSouce Property (if you don't want to pass it through its Constructor).